# Azure blobs and thumbnails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have two images clear.jpg and thumbclear.jpg, the second one is a thumbnail I 
create from the first one with the following code: 
*I am not doing any resize yet*

```
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(File.InputStream);
  MemoryStream st = new MemoryStream();
  try
  {
     bitmap.Save(st, ImageFormat.Png);
     return st;
  }
  finally
  {
     bitmap.Dispose();
  }
```

so then I upload both Images to blobs and I get their URIs and copy/paste them to
browser.
The first one
http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/media/e1a987d1-c731-4e26-9e6c-d7a63b62f661/clear.png
is working fine,

but the second one http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/media/b7ba6428-9db4-4282-8991-7a8198e7126f/thumbclear.png
gives me the following error:

**The image "http://...thumbclear.png" cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.**

So I supose it has something to do with the bitmap to stream. 
Any help will be appreciated.

****Edit**
The code I use to save the blob

```
public static CloudBlob SaveFileToBlob(MemoryStream stream, string blobContainerName, string filename, string extension, string contentType, int fileSize)
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                CloudBlobContainer _BlobContainer = SessionHelper.GetBlobContainer(blobContainerName);
                var permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
                permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
                _BlobContainer.SetPermissions(permissions);

                Guid blobid = Guid.NewGuid();
                var blob = _BlobContainer.GetBlobReference(blobid.ToString() + "/" + filename);
                blob.UploadFromStream(stream);

                blob.Metadata["FileName"] = filename;
                blob.Metadata["Extension"] = extension;
                blob.Metadata["FileSize"] = fileSize.ToString();
                blob.SetMetadata();

                blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
                blob.SetProperties();

                return blob;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks zynaps - please either provide this comment as an answer, or delete the question.

Comment: also make sure the stream gets closed and disposed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to set the stream position to zero before uploading to blob.

```
stream.Position = 0;
blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first sample:

> ```
>   Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(File.InputStream);
>   MemoryStream st = new MemoryStream();
>   try
>   {
>      bitmap.Save(st, ImageFormat.Png);
>
>
> //worked for me
>         Response.ContentType = "image/png";
>         st.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
> //--
>
>
>   }
>   finally
>   {
>      bitmap.Dispose();
>   }
> ```

AND, I found today

> ```
> Function Index() As FileContentResult
>     Dim Resim = New WebClient().DownloadData("https://dosyalar.blob.core.windows.net/dosya/kartalisveris.gif")
>     Return New FileContentResult(Resim, "image/png") '* With {.FileDownloadName = "Höbölö"}
> End Function
> ```