# How do I code PDF download from external site on Image click?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one "Download PDF" Image link, I am calling an action of a controller in order to allow users to download specific file from external site (so has given complete URL of PDF file link)

I have written following code, but its not working.

```
public virtual ActionLink OpenPDF()
{
string fileName = "http://mysite/filetodownload.pdf";
return File(fileName, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(fileName);
}
```

This controller action gets called from an Image link.. and I can see this action gets called..
When I click on image, the code gets executed, and asks to Open/Save file, but when I say Save it says "This file cannot be downloaded"

what do you think can be wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just point your link directly to the site

```
<a href="http://mysite/filetodownload.pdf" class="some_image_class">Download File</a>
```

You don't need to go through a controller for this

As a side not, if you are returning a FileResult you need to pass it a stream, a byte array, or a path to a file on disk.  You can't pass it a third party URL.  It doesn't work like that.  It is meant to work like this:

```
public virtual ActionLink OpenPDF()
{
string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Download/filetodownload.pdf");
return File(fileName, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: dude you totally ROCK SERIOUSLY

Answer (score 0):

I think

[Show images in table from database in Asp.net-mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309076/show-images-in-table-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc3/11309718#11309718)

[Azure blobs and thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645761/azure-blobs-and-thumbnails/10059294#10059294)

[ASP.NET MVC - user managment of folder with pictures (FTP?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781541/asp-net-mvc-user-managment-of-folder-with-pictures-ftp/10782161#10782161)

links as you meet the answer.